# Exclude list column from affecting search

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, column

I have a SharePoint Online list that I would like to be able to search efficiently using the list search bar. There are around 30 columns but only 5 that I want to use for the purposes of searching. The intent here is to improve the relevance of searches.

To give an example, one column I might want to search is called "Name" and is a single line text column that may contain multiple words i.e. "Big Corp International". Another column that exists in the list is "Description". This column is a multi-line text column and can at times contain a substantial paragraph. Now if I enter "Big" in an attempt to search for "Big Corp International" I may get undesirable results because one of the descriptions has the word "Big".

This lowers the overall relevance of the search results, and I would like to be able to exclude the Description and other columns from the search because they are not as relevant and too noisy. I have looked around, but all I have been able to find are results concerning the exclusion of site columns from search. Is there a way to exclude columns that only exist at the list or library level?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to exclude specific columns from SharePoint list search bar. If you are using managed properties and custom search bar then it is possible to change the managed properties settings to make then non-searchable, non-retrievable, etc. from site settings --> search schema.

Comment: Something like a Description couldn't really be made into a manged property though right?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint default "Description" column or is this a custom column you created at list level? I think you can create a managed property based on text columns as well OR map the text columns with existing managed properties (names starts with "RefineableString##". Then use those managed properties while searching.